# Questions about commentaries

Tags: discussion, scope

Would questions about clarifying things heard while watching a movie or TV episode commentary be on-topic on the main site? If someone wondered what a term or reference meant, from a **commentary** track, is that allowed?

And what about references on commentaries by a third party, ala MST3K, Film Crew, RiffTrax, Cinematic Titanic, etc?  I hope this would be considered more than merely trivia, as it **does** add understanding and enjoyment to the experience.

Comment: So what you're basically asking is if it would be Ok to ask questions about the content of commentary tracks. Did I get that right?

Comment: If you are basically asking about what some random word means, and the only link between that word and movies and/or TV is that it was mentioned in a video about movies and/or TV, I doubt that would be on topic here

Comment: @MeatTrademark IMO, no. Commentary tracks seem peripheral to me. And while asking about MST seems fine since it was a TV show, the rest, again, however illuminating it is, seems peripheral.

Comment: For posterity, I am not asking about connections between random words and videos on the internet. RiffTrax and Cinematic Titanic are legitimate businesses that also have physical releases. Same with MST3K, which also used to be a TV show (for over 10 years). And the Film Crew released 4 DVDs and I bought those in stores. This question has absolutely nothing to do with videos "about movies and/or TV."

Comment: Can you give an example question?

Comment: I forgot my original example, but something along the lines of "now it's garbage!" being shouted during an MST3K episode. It sounded familiar to me, but I couldn't place it for the longest time. (It's an *Odd Couple* reference.) Remembering this added to my enjoyment of the "experiment" the next time I saw it. **A lot.** This is not the best example, but is one. Plus, I don't expect an influx of commentary questions. "It's not a problem until it's a problem," right? Also, I hope this wasn't too timely a reply!